# Android studio 0.4.2 + Android annotations errors

Tags: android, android-studio, android-annotations

I tried to install android annotations in android studio 0.4.2 with gradle but it can't configure the MainActivity_ class

I configured ***Compiler-> Annotations proccesors*** Here's a picture ![image]

and this is a part of my **build.gradle**

```
    configurations {
    apt
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
    //android annotations
    compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.0'
    apt 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.0'
}

def getSourceSetName(variant) {
    return new File(variant.dirName).getName();
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    aptOutput = file("${project.buildDir}/source/apt_generated/${variant.dirName}")
    println "****************************"
    println "variant: ${variant.name}"
    println "manifest:  ${variant.processResources.manifestFile}"
    println "aptOutput:  ${aptOutput}"
    println "****************************"

    variant.javaCompile.doFirst {
        println "*** compile doFirst ${variant.name}"
        aptOutput.mkdirs()
        variant.javaCompile.options.compilerArgs += [
                '-processorpath', configurations.apt.getAsPath(),
                '-AandroidManifestFile=' + variant.processResources.manifestFile,
                '-s', aptOutput
        ]
    }
}
```

I can inject views in my activity but it doen't find the MainActivity_ class

In the countless tutorials that i've read says that i need to mark the ***generated*** directory as **Source** , but i can't do that with android studio 0.4.2

Any help, appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working solution has been submitted on the [github issue](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/899#issuecomment-33135768): source folders have to be configured via gradle. So the configuration for android part should look like this :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'YOUR_OTHER_PRODUCTION_SOURCE_FOLDER']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I agree with Eugen, you really should use the new android-apt plugin. This has been explained on the [wiki page](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Gradle) of AA project.
I'm gonna add a part of how to configure AA on Android studio to clarify this point.

Answer (score 2):

First of all forget about changing settings for annotation processing inside Android Studio with `gradle` project. Android Studio delegates all build processing to `gradle` and just reflects state and errors.

Second, please remove your workarounds for having code generation done in gradle and start using Hugo Visser's `android-apt` plugin: https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt

Please pay attention about how to correctly pass arguments for `android-annaotaiton` processor through plugin settings.

Success!

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into the android-apt plugin. The fact is that there are so many opinions , some outdated, and it can be confusing to find the right answer. I found each time a different gradle code snippet and none worked, so it's hard to find excactly what's wrong. Thanks again for your response